# Apache POI - add listbox (multiple Select widget)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a requirement to be able to create excel files on the fly. I'm using POI 3.7 and all is fine, but I can't find a way to add a listbox, i.e. the multiple select box just like described here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-list-box-or-combo-box-to-a-worksheet-HP010236681.aspx .

Does anyone know a way to programmatically add such listboxes / multiple select to an excel file (97 and 2007 versions) using POI.

Is this even possible?

Many thanks,

Damo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache POI documentation contains an example that shows how this can be done:

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Validation

Comment: This is only for the drop-downs and not multi select boxes. What I want can be expressed in html as <select name=mytextarea size=3 multiple>..

Comment: Anyway - I don't think it is possible at this moment in time with POI.

Comment: This link returns 404 now.